# How to insert image from dropbox into picture box using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, dropbox

I want to insert an image from Dropbox into picture box using vb.net. Do I need any declaration to get the image? Is the code below correct?

`PictureBox1.ImageLocation = ("https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ygv9rcyh3mau9iq/AACMZkQk1LjJQtHhHfnQtJnya?dl=0")`

Thanks.

Regards
Bella

Comment: If the code worked then it is obviously correct. If it didn't work, tell us what happened so that we can help diagnose the problem.

Comment: This code does not look correct. Dropbox links like "www.dropbox.com/sh/" are HTML preview pages, not file content. You'd need to get a link for the desired image file in particular, and then convert it per https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rightclic ur picture and get the full image link.
Use a webclient to download the picture.
Convert it to an image and display it:

```
Dim wc as WebClient = new WebClient()
Dim link as String = "https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AACerj-io8r78s9wMuMj89u6oImFJ3DBeSkMCqTdCHNh3g/12/251283012/jpeg/32x32/3/1501606800/0/2/Red.jpg/EJuPkuUBGEIgAigCKAQ/UMjbxEdbmCCNu2OKt_ilUDfYTahaFP6-V2bmbT4g6pM?dl=0&size=1600x1200&size_mode=3"
Dim mem as new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(link ))
Dim img as Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(mem )
PictureBox1.Image = img
```